# Substracting two Columns in MSSQL

Tags: sql-server

I've the following table:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eJRTJ.png)

I'm trying to do the following:

- Difference between present today's and previous day Closing Price.

where:

1. Bus date column represents the dates.
2. It only accepts Business Days.
3. The data in table is not arraned and is unstructred

Comment: What version of SQL Server do you use?

Answer (score 0):

Please try this:

```
SELECT t.BusDate,t.ClosingPrice
    ,t.ClosingPrice - COALESCE(LAG(t.ClosingPrice)OVER(ORDER BY t.BusDate ASC),0) AS [Difference]
FROM [YourTableName] t
;
```